# Output resources using Groovy ASTTransformer

Tags: groovy, annotations, abstract-syntax-tree

I've written a number of Java annotation processors that write some arbitrary data to text files that will be included in my class directory / jar file. I typically use code that looks like this:

```
        final OutputStream out = processingEnv
                  .getFiler()
                  .createResource(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, "", "myFile")
                  .openOutputStream();
```

I'm trying to do something similar in a groovy `ASTTransformation`. I've tried adding a new source file but that (expectedly) must be valid groovy. How do I write arbitrary resources from an `ASTTransformation`? Is it even possible?

Comment: You want to generate this resources at compile-time ? Or in runtime ?

Comment: At compile time. My understanding is that that's when an `ASTTransformation` will run, correct?

Comment: yes, I wasn't clear : compile-time, like "generating a JAR", or runtime, like "dynamically compiling & running a script"

Comment: Ah, generating a JAR.

Comment: After thinking about it a bit more, I need it to work in both scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

As part of implementing your `ASTTransformation`, you need to implement the `void visit(ASTNode[] nodes, SourceUnit source)` method. In it you can call `source.getConfiguration().getTargetDirectory()` and it will return your build output directory, e.g. `/Users/skissane/my-groovy-project/build/classes/groovy/main`). You can then write your resources into there, and whatever is packaging them into the JAR (such as Gradle) should pull them from that.

In my case, I wanted to delay writing the resources until `OUTPUT` phase – since I was creating `META-INF/services` files, and I wanted to wait until I'd seen all the annotated classes before writing them, or else I'd be repeatedly adding to them for each annotated class – so I also implemented `CompilationUnitAware`, and then in my `setCompilationUnit` method I call `unit.addPhaseOperation()` and pass it a method reference to run during `OUTPUT`. Note, if you are using a local `ASTTransformation`, `setCompilationUnit` will be called multiple times (each time on a new instance of your transformation class); to avoid adding the phase operation repeatedly, I used a map in a static field to track if I'd seen this `CompilationUnit` before or not. My `addPhaseOperation` method is called once per an output class, so I used a boolean field to make sure I only wrote the resource files out once.

Doing this caused a warning to be printed:

```
> Task :compileGroovy
warning: Implicitly compiled files were not subject to annotation processing.
  Use -implicit to specify a policy for implicit compilation.
1 warning
```

Adding this to `build.gradle` made the warning go away:

```
compileGroovy {
    options.compilerArgs += ['-implicit:none']
}
```